# define: not allowed in an expression context

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I've just started learning Racket.

I have written this procedure:

```
#lang racket

(define split
   (lambda (list)
      (define plus-list '())
      (define minus-list '())

      (cond ((null? list) '())
            (else
               (do ([i (length list) (- i 1)])
                   ((zero? i))
                   (define l (list-ref list i))
                   (define item (last-element-on-list l))

                   (cond ((= (cdr l '+)) (set! plus-list (cons list plus-list)))
                         ((= (cdr l '-)) (set! minus-list (cons list minus-list))))
               )

               (cons plus-list minus-list)
            )
      )
   )
)
```

And instead of using `(list-ref lst i)` inside de `do` I have defined a variable `l`:

```
(define (list-ref lst i) l)
```

But it seems that I cann't do that, because I get the error:

> define: not allowed in an expression context in: (define l (list-ref
>   lst i))

But there are a lot of `define` inside the `do`.

If I remove all the define inside the `do`, I have to write a lot of code and it is not easier to read and understand:

```
(define split
   (lambda (list)
      (define plus-list '())
      (define minus-list '())

      (cond ((null? list) '())
            (else
               (do ([i (length list) (- i 1)])
                   ((zero? i))

                   (cond ((= (cdr (last-element-on-list (list-ref list i)) '+)) (set! plus-list (cons (list-ref list i) plus-list)))
                         ((= (cdr (last-element-on-list (list-ref list i)) '-)) (set! minus-list (cons (list-ref list i) minus-list))))
               )

               (cons plus-list minus-list)
            )
      )
   )
)
```

How can I define a variable inside a do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53159405/633183) I see why you write the **bolded** expressions -

```
…

(cond ((= (cdr (last-element-on-list (list-ref list i)) '+))
       (set! plus-list
             (cons (list-ref list i) plus-list)))

      ((= (cdr (last-element-on-list (list-ref list i)) '-))
       (set! minus-list
             (cons (list-ref list i) minus-list))))
…
```

Your input list shown there is –

```
(define lst
  '((n 25 f +)
    (s 25 m +)
    (ll 20 no -)))
```

Your `split` is inspecting the contents of each element of `l`. `split` has overstepped its boundaries and now it *only* works for lists containing elements of this particular structure. Along with `set!`, lack of `else` in a `cond` is typically an indication you're doing something wrong. You also call `(cdr (last-element-of-list ...))`. If `last-element-of-list` returns an atom, `cdr` would throw an error here.

Consider designing `split` in a more generic way –

```
(define (split proc l)
  (define (loop l true false)
    (cond ((null? l)
           (cons true false))
          ((proc (car l))
           (loop (cdr l)
                 (cons (car l) true)
                 false))
          (else
           (loop (cdr l)
                 true
                 (cons (car l) false)))))
  (loop l '() '()))

(split (lambda (x) (> x 5))
       '(1 5 3 9 7 0 8 3 2 6 4))

;; '((6 8 7 9) 4 2 3 0 3 5 1)
```

If our list contains different elements, we can still use the same `split` procedure –

```
(split (lambda (x) (eq? '+ (cadr x)))
       '((1 +) (1 -) (2 +) (3 +) (2 -) (3 -) (4 +)))
;; '(((4 +) (3 +) (2 +) (1 +)) (3 -) (2 -) (1 -))
```

---

I think it's never too early to start learning continuation passing style. Below, `return` represents our continuation and defaults to `cons`, the same procedure we used to return the final result in our original implementation. Intuitively, a continuation represents *"the next step"* of the computation –

```
(define (split proc l (return cons)) ;; `return` is our continuation
  (if (null? l)
      ;; base case: list is empty, return empty result
      (return '() '())
      ;; inductive case: at least one `x`
      (let* ((x (car l))
             (bool (proc x)))
        (split proc          ;; tail recur with our proc
               (cdr l)       ;; ... a smaller list
               (lambda (t f) ;; ... and "the next step"
                 (if bool                        ;; if `(proc x)` returned true
                     (return (cons x t)          ;; ... cons the `x` onto the `t` result
                             f)                  ;; ... and leave the `f` the same
                     (return t                   ;; otherwise leave `t` the same
                             (cons x f))))))))   ;; ... and cons the `x` onto the `f` result
```

If we run our `split` procedure, you'll notice we get the same exact output as above. At first glance it looks like we made a mess of a nice program, however there's one distinct advantage of this implementation. Because the continuation is user-configurable, instead of `cons`, we could decide an entirely different fate for our two lists, `t` and `f` –

```
(split (lambda (x) (eq? '+ (cadr x)))
       '((1 +) (1 -) (2 +) (3 +) (2 -) (3 -) (4 +))
       (lambda (plus minus)
          (printf "plus: ~a, minus: ~a\n" plus minus)))
;; plus: ((1 +) (2 +) (3 +) (4 +)), minus: ((1 -) (2 -) (3 -))
```

Note how `plus` and `minus` were given the respective results. We didn't have to pick apart an intermediate `cons` result. More intuitively, we want `printf` to be *"the next step"*, but we only need to specify the first argument –

```
(split (lambda (x) (eq? '+ (cadr x)))
       '((1 +) (1 -) (2 +) (3 +) (2 -) (3 -) (4 +))
       (curry printf "plus: ~a, minus: ~a\n"))
;; plus: ((1 +) (2 +) (3 +) (4 +)), minus: ((1 -) (2 -) (3 -))
```

Now we've scratched the surface of functional style :D

Answer (score 1):

`do` loops are not idiomatic Racket. They are inherited from Scheme, and for whatever reason, they don’t permit internal definitions. I have never once used a `do` loop in Racket, since the `for` comprehensions are more functional, and they’re just generally easier to work with. Plus, since they originate in Racket, not in Scheme, they support internal definitions as you’d expect.

You could write your `split` function using `for/fold` instead of `do`, which has the added advantage of not needing to use `set!` (and avoiding the quadratic access time of using `list-ref` instead of iterating through the list). I’m not completely sure what your `split` function is supposed to do, as even with the internal definition removed, it does not compile, but here’s my best guess at what you might be attempting to do:

```
(define (split lst)
  (for/fold ([plus-lst '()]
             [minus-lst '()])
            ([l (in-list lst)])
    (define item (last l))
    (cond
      [(equal? item '+)
       (values (cons l plus-lst) minus-lst)]
      [(equal? item '-)
       (values plus-lst (cons l minus-lst))]
      [else
       (values plus-lst minus-lst)])))
```

Aside from the obvious restructuring to use `for/fold` instead of `do`, this code also makes the following changes over your code:

1. It uses the built-in `last` function from `racket/list` to get the last element of a list.
2. It uses `equal?` instead of `=` to compare symbols, since `=` is specifically for comparing numbers.
3. It indents things properly and puts close parentheses in idiomatic locations.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed your code using `let`, read documentation about `let` it's heavily used in Scheme/Racket. I haven't used Scheme lately so I couldn't explain it as well as it is in documentation.

Shortly it's local symbol definition/redefinition, and you can use symbol with value only in `let` body.

Short example on let

```
(define x 5)

(let ((x 10))
  (display x)) # => 10

(display x) # => 5

(let ((y 1))
  (display y)) # => 1

(display y) # = => (error)  y: undefined
```

**Your code fixed using let**

```
(define split
(lambda (list)
 (let ((plus-list '())
        (minus-list '()))

  (cond ((null? list) '())
        (else
           (do ([i (length list) (- i 1)])
               ((zero? i))
               (let ((l (list-ref list i))
                     (item (last-element-on-list l)))

               (cond ((= (cdr l '+)) (set! plus-list (cons list plus-list)))
                     ((= (cdr l '-)) (set! minus-list (cons list minus-list))))))
           (cons plus-list minus-list))))))
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This is the problem when we start to learn a language, there are a lot of things that we don't know (like let).

Comment: No problem, I added some short explanation of let I hope it can help you understand it little more

Comment: But your `(let ((plus-list '()) (minus-list '()))` is wrong, there is a missing `)`, and if I added I get the following error: `let: bad syntax (missing binding pairs or body) in: (let ((plus-list (quote ())) (minus-list (quote ()))))`

Comment: @VansFannel I just tried my latest edit of answer I posted, and everything is working with no errors, maybe when you copied it you missed some bracket.

Comment: I've copied everything in a new DrRacket window, added #lang racket, and I get the error: `l: unbound identifier in: l` in `(item (last-element-on-list l))`.

Comment: @Vans Oh, I have always preferred to use **Pretty Big** language from _Other language_ selection. That should be valid for you, I use **Scheme** not Racket, although differences are minimal.