# List passed to procedure converts into list of list inside the procedure

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I'm debugging this code on DrRacket:

```
#lang racket

(define last-element-on-list
   (lambda l
      (cond ((null? l) '())
            ((null? (cdr l)) (car l))
            (else (last-element-on-list (cdr l)))
      )
   )
)

(define lst '(
  (n 25 f +)
  (s 25 m +)
  (ll 20 no -)))

(list-ref lst 0)

(last-element-on-list (list-ref lst 0))
```

The code `(list-ref lst 0)` returns `'(n 25 f +)`, but when I get into the procedure `last-element-on-list` the parameter `l` has the value `((n 25 f +))`.

Why `l` is a list of list in procedure `last-element-on-list`?

Comment: You'll eventually put those `)` at the end of the line where they belong (instead of on their own line)

Comment: Yes.  This is the way I learn Racket. I will move it to the end of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a difference between the `(lambda (x) ...)` form and the `(lambda x ...)` form.

Observe the difference between these two examples:

```
;; Example 1.
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    (if (list? x)
      (display "x is a list!")
      (display "x is not a list"))))

(f 1)  ; Displays "x is not a list".

;; Example 2.
(define g
  (lambda x
    (if (list? x)
      (display "x is a list!")
      (display "x is not a list"))))

(g 1)  ; Displays "x is a list!".
```

The `(lambda x ...)` form allows the lambda to take any number of arguments, with all the arguments put into a list bound to `x` in the lambda's body. i.e. `x` is the list of arguments.

That's why when you give `g` a list (e.g. `(g '(1 2 3))`), `x` will be `'((1 2 3))` (a list of lists).

To fix your code:

```
(define last-element-on-list
   (lambda (l)  ; <- ATTENTION.
      (cond ((null? l) '())  ; FIXME: raise error instead.
            ((null? (cdr l)) (car l))
            (else (last-element-on-list (cdr l))))))
```

You can read more about `lambda` in [The Racket Guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html). In particular, look at section 4.4.1 (Declaring a Rest Argument).

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to raise an `error` when calling your procedure on an empty list –

```
(define last-element-of-list
  (lambda (l)
    (cond ((null? l)
           (error 'last-element-of-list "cannot get last element of empty list"))
          ((null? (cdr l))
           (car l))
          (else
           (last-element-of-list (cdr l))))))


(last-element-of-list '(1))         ;; 1
(last-element-of-list '(1 2))       ;; 2
(last-element-of-list '(1 2 3))     ;; 3
(last-element-of-list '(1 2 3 4))   ;; 4

(last-element-of-list '())          ;; error: cannot get last element of empty list
```